# Can I 'add potential together'?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, interactions

I have the Lagrangian function for a particle in an electromagnetic field

$$L = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2 + q \dot{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{r}, t) - q \phi (\mathbf{r}, t)$$

If I wanted to expand upon this, could I just add on the gravitational potential for earth to take into account gravity on earth? Ie, constructing my potential function such that

$$V(\mathbf{r}) = V_{electromagnetic} + V_{gravitational}$$

Which, ultimately, would look like

$$V(\mathbf{r}) = - q \dot{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{r}, t)  + q \phi (\mathbf{r}, t) + m\mathbf{g}\cdot \mathbf{r}.$$

In order to get the Lagrangian function

$$L = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2 + q \dot{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{r}, t) - q \phi (\mathbf{r}, t) - m\mathbf{g}\cdot \mathbf{r}.$$

Comment: As @ThomasFritsch says. Alternatively you could write a potential function for gravity in a similar way as for the electromagnetic field, a \phi_g (r,t).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add two potentials to get the total potential energy. Your total Lagrangian is correct except that $mg\textbf{r}$ is a vector and should be a scalar. You can write $mgh$ instead, where $h$ is measured from the ground level. If you insted need your gravitational potential measured from the center of the earth, you can use:

$U_g = -\frac{GMm}{r}$